# How can i count the number of followers using parse saved data as shown:

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

i have saved my followers list as shown in the table image
[image]

in the "user" column , i've saved the objectId of user being followed and in the "follower" column i've saved the currentUser (follower)
now i want to get the number of followers of each user.. how can i do that?

Comment: What does your code look like so far? What have you attempted?

Comment: not getting any idea to do so. :-| <<a beginner>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse Query for counting objects
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-counting-objects
Where you can execute 1 query to get followers count of 1 user. Which can easily max out parse api limit i.e. (counting object query 160 requests per minute). For this Parse and Me, both not recommend you to use counting Objects especially if you expect significant number of users.

Parse Recommendation to avoid Count Operations
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#performance-avoid-count-operations

You should use parse cloud code(https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code) and have a key in your User table which can keep record of current followers count for that user.

Cloud code in your case.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Followers", function(request) {
    if(request.object.existed() == true)
        // No need to increment count for update due to some reason
        return;
    });
    // Get the user id for User
    var userID = request.object.get("user");// Or request.object.get("user").id;
    // Query the user in actual User Table
    var UserQuery = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(UserQuery);
    query.get(userID).then(function(user) {
    // Increment the followersCount field on the User object
        user.increment("followersCount");
        user.save();
    }, function(error) {
        throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
    });
});
```

Unfollowing might also happen, Leaving After Delete practise to you
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code-afterdelete-triggers

Comment: This answer is outdated now. According to recent Parse docs, the restriction on limiting object queries have been lifted. There isn't a restriction on requests per minute and counts for object above 1,000 are now possible. https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#counting-objects

However, saving the count with an afterSave may still be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Parse Server `countObjectsInBackground()` function for achieve your task. It worked for me. I have used iOS SDK version `1.17.3`.

Here is the **Swift 4** sample code:

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "yourTableName")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: "yourUserId")
    query.countObjectsInBackground { (count: Int32, error: Error?) in
    if error == nil {
        print("My followers number: \(count)")
    }
```

For more information: https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#counting-objects

Hope it works.